# The table row gets offset when dragging, using JQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, border-spacing

I have a table that uses border-spacing to separate rows.

When using JQuery sortable - and it works - the row jumps down when beeing moved, can this be fixed?

This code demonstrates:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#items").sortable();
  $("#items").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0 20px;
  background-color: #cda;
}

td {
  width: 170px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody id="items">
    <tr>
      <td class="list">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="list">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="list">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is an inherent problem with moving table cells dynamically. Is it possible you can use *literally* any other element for this? A set of `div`, for example?

Comment: Well maybe, it wouldn't be impossible, but why can't tables be used?

Comment: Can you explain 'inherent problem'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I added a class to the dragged element,

```
.up{
margin-top: -20px;
}
```

(It seems to correspond to the value of `border-spacing`)

The adding was by making the sortable call like this:

```
$(function () {
$("#items").sortable({
placeholder: "highlight",
start: function (event, ui) {
ui.item.toggleClass("up");
},
stop: function (event, ui) {
ui.item.toggleClass("up");
}
});
$("#items").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I tried to use draggedClass: "up", in the call, but nothing happened